# Non-deductible IRA contributions withdrawal

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, ira

Last year (2020), I contributed for the first time to a traditional IRA from my savings, without knowing it would be non-deductible due to my 401k contributions.

I think I read that I can withdraw my non-deductible contributions before April 2021 without having to pay a penalty.

- Is that correct?
- Do I need to provide some documents to the company managing my IRA?
- Do I need to file something special with my tax return, or is it just as if the IRA never existed?
- Should I do something else than withdraw it?

Comment: Last year was 2021, April 2021 has passed long time ago. Are you sure about your timeline?

Comment: Also, have you considered backdoor Roth conversion instead?